# Jscript + jquery + an example of basic difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I am new to learning JS and would like to get a better understanding of this concept, so apologies in advance for my ignorance or simplicity of this question. I am basically trying to build a simple quiz game to learn JavaScript.

Basically I am trying to understand the difference between these 2 versions:

[JavaScript example](http://jsfiddle.net/H9zCT/)

[Jquery example](http://jsfiddle.net/PJn9Z/)

Basically I am trying to understand the difference in these 2 lines:

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "<b>Question " + questionIndex +"</b>: " + allQuestions[0][questionIndex-1];
```

JQuery

```
$("#question").text("<b>Question " + questionIndex +"</b>: " + allQuestions[0][questionIndex-1])
```

The JavaScript version will display the "Question X:" in bold but it won't in Jquery version. Why? And how do I make the Jquery version bold part work? Or any other advice in general on this?

tks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.text()` sets the text, not the HTML. Use `.html()` instead:

```
$("#question").html("<b>Question " + questionIndex +"</b>: " + allQuestions[0][questionIndex-1])
```

Also, JScript isn't JavaScript. You probably mean JavaScript.

Comment: Actually JScript is Microsoft implementation of JavaScript

Comment: @DaveJust: ECMAScript, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's `document.getElementById("elementId").innerHTML ="your text/html"` equivalent in jquery is `$("#elementId").html("your text/html")`

Answer (score 0):

`.html()`  jQuery function gets/sets the HTML of any element.

`.text()` jQuery function gets/sets the text (innertext) of any element.